# Let $T:\mathbb{R}_n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}_n$ the linear operator defined by $T(p(x))=p(x)+p'(x)$ Calculate $det(T)$

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Let $T:\mathbb{R}_n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}_n$ the linear operator defined by $T(p(x))=p(x)+p'(x)$ Calculate $det(T)$

**My work:**

Let $B=\{1,x,x^2,...,x^n\}$ a basis for $\mathbb{R}_n$.

Then, 

$T(1)=1$
$T(x)=x+1$
$T(x^2)=x^2+2x$
.

.

.

$T(x^n)=x^n+nx^{n-1}$

This implies,

$[T_{BB}]=\begin{pmatrix}
1 && 1 && 0 && 0 && ... && 0\\
0 && 1 && 2 && 0 && ... && 0\\
0 && 0 && 1 && 3 && ... && 0\\
.\\
.\\
.\\
0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && ... && n\\
0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && ... &&1\\
\end{pmatrix}$

As $det(T)=det([T_B])$ and $det([T_B])=det\begin{pmatrix}
1 && 1 && 0 && 0 && ... && 0\\
0 && 1 && 2 && 0 && ... && 0\\
0 && 0 && 1 && 3 && ... && 0\\
.\\
.\\
.\\
0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && ... && n\\
0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && ... &&1\\
\end{pmatrix}=1$

then $det(T)=1$.

I don't sure of my result. I think i have a mistake. Can someone help me?

Comment: Looks good to me.  Just use `\det` instead of `det` in LaTeX to get an operator in an upright (not italic) font.

Comment: Thanks for you review, and thanks for your correction. Have a good day@MatthewLeingang

Comment: Some nitpicking: Your basis has $n+1$ elements, so it spans a vector space isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$.

Comment: Usually people write $\mathbb{R}[X]_{\leq n}$ for the space of polynomials with coefficients in $\mathbb{R}$ of degree at most $n$. This space indeed has dimension $n+1$ as you wrote down (the above comment is mistaken). Your work is fine, good job!

Comment: You can also do: $(T-rI)(p)=0$ has solutions $P(x)=C$ for $r=1$. If $r\neq1$ then $(1-r)P+P'=0$, from where $P(x)=Ce^{-(1-r)x}$, or $P(x)=0$. Therefore, the only eigenvalue of $T$ is $r=1$. Since the determinant is the product of the eigenvalues, it follows that the determinant is $1$.